Proxy Server Error While Sending API Token Request
Hey hi i am having this error while sending API token request on IBM Quantum Platform (using python   ) - " ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.quantum-computing.ibm.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /runtime/jobs?limit=10&offset=0&exclude_params=true (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))".
And this is the proxy sever info for my env -
(IMGQ) 18:37 ~ $ env | grep -i proxy
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,api.quantum-computing.ibm.com
https_proxy=http://proxy.server:3128
http_proxy=http://proxy.server:3128
So how to solve the issue ?
I was trying to send api token request toIBM Quantum Platform for 127qbit backend.
I hope for it's smooth execution but that's not happened here.
